# Index 16 out of bounds for length 16 Array of Tiles in RPG

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, tile

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        
        int worldCol = 0;
        int worldRow = 0;
        
        while(worldCol < map.maxWorldCol && worldRow < map.maxWorldRow) {
            
            int tileNum = mapTileNum[worldCol][worldRow];
            
            int worldX = worldCol * map.tileSize;
            int worldY = worldRow * map.tileSize;
            int screenX = worldX - map.player.worldX + map.player.screenX;
            int screenY = worldY - map.player.worldY + map.player.screenY;
            
            g2.drawImage(tile[tileNum].image, screenX, screenY, map.tileSize, map.tileSize, null);
            worldCol++;
            
            if(worldCol == map.maxWorldCol) {
                worldCol = 0;
                worldRow++;
            }
            
        }
```

Im having trouble drawing my tiles for my RPG and I cant figure out what that problem is. It drew before but then I created a camera and a larger map than my previous 16 x 12 map. It is now 50x 50 and the screen size is still 16 x 12. my tiles are in an array that got data from a text document.

The tile images are image files that are linked to a number.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16 out of bounds for length 16
    at tile.TileManager.draw(TileManager.java:117)
    at vardasAdventure.Map.paintComponent(Map.java:161)
```

Comment: which line is 117?

Comment: Are tile numbers, as in the `tileNum` variable, 0-based or 1-based?  If 1-based, there's your problem.

Comment: I would look at what `int tileNum = mapTileNum[worldCol][worldRow];` is returning and how many elements actually exist in the `tile` array.  Personally, I'd have a "manager" class of some kind which could take a `worldCol` and `worldRow` value a return a "title", possibly with the physical x/y coordinates already calculated - basically a conversion from "virtual" or "physical" space

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through an array but exceed the array size.
Array indexes (the numbers you put in the [] brackets to set / retrieve data) start at 0 and go to the arrays length -1.
So some example sizes would be:
Size: 16, Indexes 0 - 15 -
Size 24, Indexes 0 - 23
Because Java starts counting at 0 and not at 1 (as hoomans do).

You should instead just move the if-statement to the top of the while-loop.